# How to permissively decode a UTF-8 bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, error-handling, decode

I need to decode a UTF-8 sequence, which is stored in a bytearray, to a string.

The UTF-8 sequence might contain erroneous parts. In this case I need to decode as much as possible and (optionally?) substitute invalid parts by something like "?".

```
# First part decodes to "ABÄC"
b = bytearray([0x41, 0x42, 0xC3, 0x84, 0x43])
s = str(b, "utf-8") 
print(s)

# Second part, invalid sequence, wanted to decode to something like "AB?C"
b = bytearray([0x41, 0x42, 0xC3, 0x43])
s = str(b, "utf-8")
print(s)
```

What's the best way to achieve this in Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several builtin error-handling [schemes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) for encoding and decoding `str` to and from `bytes` and `bytearray` with e.g. [`bytearray.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.decode). For example:

```python
>>> b = bytearray([0x41, 0x42, 0xC3, 0x43])
```

```python
>>> b.decode('utf8', errors='ignore')  # discard malformed bytes
'ABC'
```

```python
>>> b.decode('utf8', errors='replace')  # replace with U+FFFD
'AB�C'
```

```python
>>> b.decode('utf8', errors='backslashreplace')  # replace with backslash-escape
'AB\\xc3C'
```

In addition, you can write your own error handler and [register](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error) it:

```python
import codecs

def my_handler(exception):
    """Replace unexpected bytes with '?'."""
    return '?', exception.end

codecs.register_error('my_handler', my_handler)
```

```python
>>> b.decode('utf8', errors='my_handler')
'AB?C'
```

All of these error handling schemes can also be used with the `str()` constructor as in your question:

```python
>>> str(b, 'utf8', errors='my_handler')
'AB?C'
```

... although it's more idiomatic to use `str.decode()` explicitly.